# Question moved, can it be moved back?

Tags: support, migration

One of my questions was moved from photo.stackexchange to softwarerecs.stackexchange.

Here is the post: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/steganography-software

The question is about using steganography to digitally protect photos, but it seems that it's not commonly known by every photographer. However it's a question context, I think that I'll have more chance to get an answer by experienced photographers than on a software recommandation site.

Is there a way to contact the person who moved this question or someone else and ask to move it back?

Comment: Although I realize you'd prefer the audience of [Photo.SE], that question _is_ a question for a recommendation. These are off-topic on all Stack Exchange sites except [softwarerecs.SE]. In fact, the latter was made for the very purpose of giving such questions a home.

Comment: You can click the link at the bottom of your question to go back to [where you originally posted it](http://photo.stackexchange.com/posts/48531/revisions). There you can see who migrated your question and leave a comment for them. However, since it was a Photography moderator, odds are pretty good that the question is off-topic for that site.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Questions asking for recommendations are off-topic on [so] and [su] but not on every SE site (e.g. [unix.se] and [apple.se] have no rule against them). I don't know about Photo.SE's policy.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Actually the migrated stub is locked, so TTT can't leave a comment on Photo (nor even flag, I think). Since the migrating mod hasn't participated on SR, there's no way to contact him on SR. Chat or meta would be ways to contact the moderator.

Comment: In any case, I'm casting the 5th close vote on SR: the question isn't well-defined. Now the question is plain closed on Photo, so you can comment there. If Photo doesn't want the question, you're welcome to re-ask on SR, with the requested clarification.